# print multiple unserialize array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I insert image_url and title and alt data using serialize methods into MySQL database like this :

```
a:3:{i:0;a:4:{i:0;s:48:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/butterfly_001.jpg";i:1;s:43:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/IMG_4181.jpg";i:2;s:43:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/swan_002.jpg";i:3;s:45:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/zzmed copy.jpg";}i:1;a:4:{i:0;s:19:"test_title";i:1;s:20:"test_title1";i:2;s:25:"test_title2";i:3;s:24:"677777777777777777777777";}i:2;a:4:{i:0;s:19:"test_alt";i:1;s:21:"test_alt1";i:2;s:21:"test_alt2";i:3;s:26:"77888888888888888888888888";}}
```

PHP CODE:

```
$value['gallery_data'] = serialize((array(array_values($_POST['image_url']), array_values($_POST['image_title']), array_values($_POST['image_alt']))));
```

Now, i can print image_url like this :

```
$all1 = Access::fetch("SELECT * FROM " . GALLERIES . " WHERE id = ?", $id);
$array= unserialize($all1['0']['name']);
echo($array['0']['1']);
```

Output is:

```
uploads/media/galleries/nature/butterfly_001.jpg
```

BUT,i need to print list all image_url and image_title and image_alt for each id Like This :

```
uploads/media/galleries/nature/butterfly_001.jpg - test_title - test_alt
uploads/media/galleries/nature/IMG_4181.jpg      - test_title1 - test_alt1
uploads/media/galleries/nature/zzmed copy.jpg    - test_title2 - test_alt2
```

how do can i print this in `foreach` method?!

Answer (score 0):

My English is not good. So, I write this code to you. I hope this helpful.

```
    $un_arr = unserialize($arr);
    $export = NULL;
    array_walk_recursive($un_arr, function($val, $key) use (&$export ) {
        $img_extension = array('.jpg','.jpeg');
        foreach($extension as $value){
          if(strpos($val,$value) != false){
             $export  .= $val . '<br>';
          }
        }
    });
    echo $export ;
```

If this line (strpos($val,'.jpg') != false) not work. You can change to strpos($val,'.jpg') !== false. I hope this help you

I fix for many extension image. Hope this help you

Comment: image_url is dynamic extension:`JPEG, PNG, GIF`.